# Is there any possibility on iOS to auth in instagram account not using web view, but using instagram app installed on the device?

Tags: ios, instagram

I have implement instagram auth using webview and it works, but I want to open instagram app that is already installed on the device and use it to auth user.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't. Instagram has not provided this facility yet for iOS.